# Save the value of a function in a variable, which returns random values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´d like to save the value of a function, which returns random values from an .xml file in a variable and update the variable everytime a new value is generated by the function.

To illustrate: This is my function

```
function getNewValue() {
return videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
}
```

I´d like to save the value which was generated in a variable e.g "currentValue", so everytime the function is called, the "currentValue" changes to the value which was generated.

Something like:

```
var currentValue;
function getNewValue() {
return videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
currentValue = getNewValue();
}
```

won´t work because the function generates a new value which isn´t the old one..

any ideas? Thank you

Comment: getNewValue is never reached, since you return before it is executed.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
var currentValue;
function getNewValue() {
    currentValue =videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
    return currentValue;
}
```

You were returning the `getNewValue` function before a value was assigned to the `currentValue`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I´d like to return my value in a Div like that $('#currentVideoDiv').html('Currently Playing:' + currentValue); But it just returns "function getNewValue()... how can i display the actual value?

Comment: looks like you are calling `currentValue = getNewValue` somewhere, are you doing anything like that

Comment: You can see more of my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274897/get-the-current-value-of-a-function-which-returns-random-values-youtube-api  would be nice if you would take a look at that. It is the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentValue;

function getNewValue() {
  return videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
}

currentValue = getNewValue();
```

I'm more inclined to do it this way since it's more readable, to me at least. Calling just getNewValue() and setting the variable inside doesn't tell me that I'm actually setting currentValue variable when I call this function some place else.

Comment: The problem is, that getNewValue() is called from another function. After that i want to save the value in a variable to know, which value was set. I don´t want to save a new random value in currentValue afterwords